# What are all the mission rating requirements in Hitman: Blood Money?

Tags: hitman-blood-money

Is there a complete list of every mission rating and requirement of getting that rating?

So far I have seen only incomplete lists

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You're making it sound like each level has a range of requirements, where it should be pretty much the same requirements to get a specific rating in each level.

Comment: What lists have you seen, and how do you know they are incomplete?

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.